# How to make a horizontally scrollable cell in a datatable

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

This is with PrimeFaces, but I think the question applies equally to a standard JSF datatable.

I have a datatable column where the entry is being word wrapped because the content can be quite long.  To make the display more readable, I would prefer the content to be not wrapped, but instead provide horizontal scrolling to view whatever content doesn't appear by default.

I am sure this a simple CSS modification but my proficiency is very low.

```
<p:dataTable ... >

    <p:column headerText="Book Title">
         <h:outputText value="#{book.title}" style="???" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is only possible when the text is enclosed in a [block-level HTML element](http://www.htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/block.html) with a definied width and text-wrapping disabled and the element in question has the CSS property `overflow:scroll` or at least `overflow-x:scroll` definied.

So, in plain HTML terms, that would basically be the following approach:

```
<div style="width: 200px; white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: scroll;">
    Some really really lengthy book title about a really really lengthy book.
</div>
```

In PrimeFaces `<p:column>` terms, that would be:

```
<p:column styleClass="scrollableCell">
    #{book.title}
</p:column>
```

with

```css
.ui-datatable td.scrollableCell div.ui-dt-c {
    width: 200px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Note that you don't need to bring in any div, the `<p:column>` already does that.

#### See also:

- [How do I override default PrimeFaces CSS with custom styles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8768317/how-do-i-override-those-classes-defined-in-primefaces-css/8774997#8774997)

Comment: well that worked just fine thanks once again.  Someday I am going to learn CSS.   This should probably be a standard feature of PF.