# How to Fix Primefaces Datatable column width and implement inner cell scroll

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces(Version 3.5) DataTable to display certain data.
How do I make only one **CELL** scrollable if its data exceeds than other cells in same row.?By keeping Column Width fixed[***I could not fix the Column width also***].
Here is the Screen Shot:

[image]

Please Suggest any best approach to achieve this, may by truncating data and adding **...** at end.
But again I can not fix the width of column.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make a horizontally scrollable cell in a datatable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13516642/how-to-make-a-horizontally-scrollable-cell-in-a-datatable)

Comment: Hi BelusC thanks for the reply. I saw that other question it was helpful.    
Can you please tell how to FIX the with of column.?

Comment: Click the link in my previous comment for the answer.

Comment: Thanks BelusC. You have been very helpful all the time,through all of my questions. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

There is css for this:

```
.ui-datatable thead th, .ui-datatable tbody td, .ui-datatable tfoot td {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

change it to normal.